# Como añadir un salto de linea en una cadena

Tags: c, string, archivo

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que consistia en pasar palabras a su respectivo fichero dependiendo de su dificultad, por ejemplo tengo un fichero con una palabra pepe-F;manzana-F;
Las que tienen una F tienen que ir al archivo de facil y como estas dos palabras la tienen me las pasa, pero me las pone tal que así pepemanaza esto con las faciles e igual con las dificiles,normales.... Os muestro con fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si hago un fprintf(file,"\n");

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Deja como mucha separación y lo que quiero es que esten una de bajo de otra sin un salto de linea tan grande.

Mis funciones para añadir a los ficheros:

```
void generarFicheros(){
    FILE *f,*facil,*normal,*dificil,*muydificil;
    char cadenaAux[MAX_STRING];
    char cadenaDificultad[MAX_STRING];
    f=fopen("palabras.txt","rt");
    facil=fopen("./FicherosOrdenados/facil.txt","w+");
    normal=fopen("./FicherosOrdenados/normal.txt","w+");
    dificil=fopen("./FicherosOrdenados/dificil.txt","w+");
    moltdificil=fopen("./FicherosOrdenados/muydificil.txt","w+");
        char caracter;
        while(feof(f)==0){
            obtenerPalabra(f,caracter,cadenaAux);
            obtenirDificultad(f,caracter,cadenaDificultad);
            if(strcmpi(cadenaDificultad,"F")==0){
                fputs(cadenaAux,facil);
            }else if(strcmpi(cadenaDificultad,"N")==0){
                fputs(normal,cadenaAux);
            }else if(strcmpi(cadenaDificultad,"D")==0){
                fprintf(dificil,cadenaAux,'\n');
            }else if(strcmpi(cadenaDificultad,"MD")==0){
                fputs(cadenaAux,muydificil);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nEls fitxers han sigut generats");
    fclose(f);
    fclose(facil);
    fclose(normal);
    fclose(dificil);
    fclose(muydificil);
}

void obtenerPalabra(FILE *f,char caracter,char cadenaAux[MAX_STRING]){
    int i =0;
    caracter=fgetc(f);

    while(caracter!='-' && i<MAX_STRING){
        cadenaAux[i]=caracter;
        caracter=fgetc(f);
        i++;
    }
    cadenaAux[i]='\0';
}

void obtenirDificultad(FILE *f,char caracter,char cadenaDificultad[MAX_STRING]){
    int i=0;
    caracter=fgetc(f);
    while(caracter!=';' && i<MAX_STRING){
        cadenaDificultad[i]=caracter;
        caracter=fgetc(f);
        i++;
    }
    cadenaDificultad[i]='\0';
}
```

Comment: ¿No podría ser que `obtenerPalabra()` te esté generando de alguna manera strings vacios? Podrías intentar filtrarlos antes de escribirlos al archivo.

Comment: Viendo tu primer imagen más bien pareciera que de alguna manera `obtenerPalabra()` genera saltos de línea `\n`, porque en el primer archivo existen los mismos saltos de línea. Podrías filtrar los resultados de `obtenerPalabra()` para eliminar cualquier salto de línea extra.

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @FranAcuna, el block de notas de windows interpreta como salto de línea la secuencia `\r\n`, un solo `\n` no va a generar un salto de línea en este editor ... pero eso no quiere decir que ese caracter no se encuentre en tu archivo ... si usas wordpad, notepad++ u otro editor es posible que obtengas resultados diferentes. Bienvenido al mundo de la informática donde hasta los archivos de texto pueden tener diferentes interpretaciones

Answer (score -1):

Hay varias maneras de hacer saltos en línea. Yo diría que la más fácil es poniendo por ejemplo con un alert sería:

```
alert(`Hola
que
tal`)
```